# Can't add 'ZXing 2.1.1' to windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, nuget, zxing

I'm new to .NET developent, I'm trying to create a Windows phone 8.1 app to read a qr code using ZXing.net but when I try to install the package by right click in references and going to Manage NuGet packeges, I'm getting the error:

Could not install package 'ZXing 2.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I read in another post that I have to unlock a DLL but I don't know where is the DLL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ZXing NuGet package does not support Windows Phone it only contains an assembly for the full .NET framework.

Try the [ZXing.Net NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net/) instead. This NuGet package supports Windows Phone projects that have a target framework of WindowsPhoneApp.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, with the ZXing.net package I'm getting the error  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: The "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" I solved by going to the C:\Users\{My user}\.nuget\packages\ZXing.Net folder and deleting the folder inside it.